# Receiving NPE while using Viewbinding in Fragments in Java - Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-viewbinding

I am using viewBinding for a fragment in Java. I'm receiving Null Pointer Exception after clearing the binding value in onDestroyView().

```
@Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        binding = null; 
        super.onDestroyView();
    }
```

If I remove the above code, then its working fine but I'm getting a memory leak. So, Is there any solution to clear the binding reference in onDestroyView() and not get NPE.

I am creating the binding variable in onCreateView() and accessing it in onViewCreated() and onActivityCreated(). But I received a NPE while accessing it from onActivityCreated()

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'com.nmbl.app.databinding.Clipboard com.nmbl.app.databinding.FragmentMain.clClipboard' on a null object reference

Comment: Where do you have the NPE? Of course you shouldn't be usinf the binding after it has been cleared.

Comment: Share your stacktrace.

Comment: I am creating the binding variable in onCreateView() and accessing it in onViewCreated() and onActivityCreated(). But I received a NPE while accessing it from onActivityCreated() @laalto

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'com.nmbl.app.databinding.Clipboard com.nmbl.app.databinding.FragmentMain.clClipboard' on a null object reference